# Generate is not generating the codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, generator

I'm trying to give a generate any, and it will not, this error appears, and sometimes nothing appears, it keeps running forever, and nothing appears. What is going on? I'm new to this area.

```
root@ubuntu:~/Projeto/Projeto_testes/teste_projeto_generator# rails g scaffold User name email
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
root@ubuntu:~/Projeto/Projeto_testes/teste_projeto_generator#
```

Comment: `rails g scaffold User name email` works for me. The warning however implies that you are running a recent version of Ruby with an older version of Rails. Upgrading Rails (or downgrading Ruby) could fix the problem.

Comment: How can I do this? I already tried the original documentation, but I do not know how to do it ... I did not understand how to do it.

Comment: I believe it's worth getting either Rbenv (I use this) or rvm (I ran into a couple of issues with rvm on MacOSX) in order to manage your ruby stuff. They allow to download and install ruby versions, set a "global" ruby version and gem set, and/or local ruby versions for certain projects, along with the gemset needed on a needed basis. I found it pretty straitghtforward to install and use.

Comment: I tried to use rvm, but some very strange problems appeared, so I downloaded rbenv, but it still gives problem, the problem is not in the gemfile? I do not know, like I said, I'm new to this area. How do I define a version that rails have to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not solve it permanently, but I found a solution to circumvent the error.
When I give a new rails, it generates the gem file, there will be specified the rails version, I just change the generated gemfile, the one I "created":

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'openssl', '2.0.4'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: '4-2-stable'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 4.0.0'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

I could not use the rbenv nor rvm to upgrade my rails, so I do this "adjustment".